# Can not run batch file from Run box even after added to Path

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, python, run-dialog

I am trying to run a batch file from the Run box. I am very new to Python and going through some introductory courses. It is a simple 'Hello World! batch file called hello.bat:

```
@py C:\Users\user name\MyPythonScripts\hello.py %* 
@pause
```

I have added the file path C:\Users'user name'\MyPythonScripts to the Path System Variable.

When I open the Run box and type hello and run it, the Command Window opens and displays the below error:

```
C:\Python3\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Users\user name': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The user name in the file path has two white spaces(ex. First Last Suffix). The file will also not run when I try to execute it by double clicking on the file as the same command window error appears.

Could someone let me know why I get this error even though the file is added to the Path variable?

Comment: Add quotes around your path. It includes a space

Comment: In the Path Variable Value I have "C:\Users\my name\MyPythonScripts"; and am still getting the same error.

Comment: Also add the quotes _in your batch_. `@py "C:\Users\user name\MyPythonScripts\hello.py" %*`

Comment: @jamesjrz1 Anytime you reference a path that contains a space character, you’ll need to wrap it in quotes. So Michael Harvey is correct in saying that the batch file also needs to contain quotes around the path. This sort of issue can be determined because your error only references a part of the path and that it cannot find it: specifically, it could find the file `C:\Users\user name` and not a statement that it couldn’t find `C:\Users\user name\MyPythonScripts\hello.py`

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you both MichaelHarvey and JG7 for your help!